# sql get available records between two hours

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with the following values ​​and I need to display the names that are on schedule available

---

```
Name | EntryTime|ExitTime  |BreakStart |BreakEnd 

David| 06:00    | 18:00    | 06:30     | 8:00 |
Kim  | 18:00    | 06:00    | 20:00     | 21:00|
Jess | 06:30    | 15:00    | 12:00     | 13:00|
Mike | 18:00    | 06:00    | 19:00     | 20:00|
```

For example:

```
If the hours is 20:30
   the query return Kim
If the hours is 11:00
   the query return David, Jess
```

I have this but don't work when i need return the name of Kim or Mike

```
SELECT Name FROM employees 
WHERE (EntryTime > @time AND ExitTime < @time)
AND (@time not between  BreakStart AND BreakEnd)
```

Comment: I'm having trouble interpreting your table. Let's look at David. He shows up at 6:00 AM. So far sounds reasonable. His break starts 12 hours later at 6PM. Doesn't sound right. He  then stays on break all night long and ends his break at 6:30 AM the next day. Again doesn't sound really like a break. Then he goes back to for an hour and a half and goes home. Is that really what this is saying?

Comment: The header should probably be `Name|EntryTime|ExitTime|BreakStart|BreakEnd`

Comment: That's because entry time to break time spans midnight, you need a date in there or you need to rework the table in terms of durations, e.g. Kim starts at 18:00, works for twelve hours ans then starts again as 12:00 and works for 1 hour.

Comment: sorry, I invested the names of the columns. XD

Comment: Still a spanning midnight issue 19:00 > 06:00..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the example with "Kim", you don't seem to care about breaks.  I think the following is the logic you want:

```
SELECT Name
FROM employees 
WHERE (EntryTime < ExitTime and @time between EntryTime and ExitTime) or
      (ExitTime < EntryTime and @time not between ExitTime and EntryTime);
```

I generally don't advocate using `between with dates and times.  In this case, it makes the logic readable.